# Why is Entity Framework changing the name of a table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In my `DbContext` I have the following:

```
public DbSet<OrgProperty> OrgProperties { get; set; }
public DbSet<SystemProperty> SystemProperties { get; set; }
```

And these are defined as follows:

```
public class OrgProperty : Property
{
    public OrgProperty(string key, string value) : base(key, value)
    {
    }

    public OrgProperty()
    {
    }
}

public class SystemProperty : Property
{
    public SystemProperty(string key, string value) : base(key, value)
    {
    }

    public SystemProperty()
    {
    }
}

public class Property : IPkIsId
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Property(string key, string value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public Property()
    {
        Key = Value = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

In the generated database it has a table `Property`, and no table `OrgProperty` or `SystemProperty`. Why?

Comment: [Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov First off, thank you. Second, I can force this to distinct tables by calling on these two models `IEntityTypeConfiguration.Configure()`. Is it better to call `ToTable()` or `UseTptMappingStrategy()()`? TIA